# Edit the Tab font in Moonrise Theme

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, themes

I am messing around with the ui of eclipse right now and found moonrise theme found here

https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/blob/master/README.md

. I like it much more than the Dark juno and those are really the only 2 i found. So the theme is great and all but the tab font is a little ... not me i suppose. I read how to change it is to go into the CSS file once you extract it from the jar file, but after that i dont know how to save the stuff as a jar file again and place it back in the eclipse dropins folder.

thanks!

Comment: why minus? its a simple question someone might know. pretty rude imo

Answer (score 4):

Based on both the question and the answer, I managed to change the tabs font on Windows 7, here's how:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open `<eclipse-installation-directory>/ plugins/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui_0.8.4.jar` (or whichever version you have) in an archive editor (WinRar, 7zip, etc.)
3. Open `themes/css/moonrise-ui-standalone.css` for editing (right click->edit)
4. Comment out all occurrences of `font-family: 'Segoe Print';`, i.e. replace them with `/*font-family: 'Segoe Print';*/`
5. Save the file and exit the archive editor. If prompted to update the archive, click yes.
6. Start Eclipse.

Comment: In last moonrise version, used font is Calibry. So, search for `font-family: 'Calibri';`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to extract the whole jar archive, just open it with an archive explorer (eg. if you are on windows use winrar, 7zip, etc.), open or extract the css file, change the font size properties as written in the readme, save it and then drag the updated css file into the archive explorer, you'll be prompted to overwrite the old one. That's all.