# increase font size of Project Explorer tree in Eclipse Photon

Tags: css, eclipse, themes, pydev

Have been tweaking the colours and font sizes of the desktop of Eclipse with Pydev (Photon Release 4.8.0) on Xfce desktop on Debian stable to the way I want it. Python interpreter window and Terminal had to be tweaked as they were bright white unlike the rest of the moonrise theme. Then I managed to increase the font size of the code window quite easily. The Project Explorer tree however remains tiny, it might also be due to the monitor resolution. I tried increasing the font in **Xcfe Settings Manager > Appearance > Fonts > Default font** but all that did was make the menu bar at the top bigger, not the tree.

Then tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47740263/4288043) solution where as described, this css:

```
.MPart Tree {
    font-family: Consolas;
    font-size: 14;
}
```

is added to the tail of these two files:

```
.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_default_gtk.css
.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_default_win.css
```

..but again, as one commenter there said, it did not work for Photon.

Is this because of the Moonrise theme?

I ran `find -name "*.css"` in my home directory to see what else there was, but the selection is vast:

```
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4-dark.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/high-contrast.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4-dark_win.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4-dark_mac.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_default_gtk.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_basestyle.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_default_win.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_default_mru_on_win7.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/dark/e4-dark_preferencestyle.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/dark/e4-dark_globalstyle.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/dark/e4-dark_partstyle.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/dark/e4-dark_basestyle.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_classic_winxp.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_default_mac.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547/css/e4_classic_win7.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_6.5.0.201809011628/css/dark/e4-pydev-dark_preferencestyle.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/macosx_narrow_book.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/intro/css/overview.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/intro/css/migrate.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/intro/css/whatsnew.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/book.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/disabled_book.css
./.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.8.0.v20180611-0500/narrow_book.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/214/0/.cp/intro/css/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/214/0/.cp/intro/css/samples.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/214/0/.cp/intro/css/migrate.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/214/0/.cp/intro/css/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/214/0/.cp/intro/css/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/136/0/.cp/help/book.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/136/0/.cp/intro/css/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/136/0/.cp/intro/css/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/136/0/.cp/intro/css/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/152/0/.cp/intro/css/default.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/255/0/.cp/intro/css/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/255/0/.cp/intro/css/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/404/0/.cp/intro/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/shared/html/shared.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/root.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/webresources.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/firststeps.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/shared.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/rtl.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/samples.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/ltr.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/font-relative.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/migrate.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/font-absolute.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/standby.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/circles/html/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/root.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/webresources.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/firststeps.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/shared.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/rtl.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/samples.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/ltr.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/font-relative.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/migrate.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/font-absolute.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/standby.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/slate/html/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/root.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/webresources.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/firststeps.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/shared.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/rtl.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/samples.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/ltr.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/font-relative.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/qroot.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/migrate.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/font-absolute.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/standby.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/solstice/html/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/root.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/webresources.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/firststeps.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/shared.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/rtl.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/samples.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/ltr.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/font-relative.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/migrate.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/font-absolute.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/standby.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/436/0/.cp/themes/purpleMesh/html/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/303/0/.cp/intro/css/overview.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/303/0/.cp/intro/css/whatsnew.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/303/0/.cp/intro/css/tutorials.css
./eclipse/java-photon/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/303/0/.cp/book.css
./eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform/splash-fix.css
./eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform/color-definitions-fix.css
./eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform/colors-org.eclipse.egit.ui-1849137576.css
./eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform/colors-org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.css--1027399938.css
./eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform/colors-org.eclipse.jdt.ui-326703266.css
```

Also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124629/how-can-i-configure-the-font-size-for-the-tree-item-in-the-package-explorer-in-e).

*update:*

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974508/4288043) answer too which was specific to the Moonrise theme and involved editing a jar file. Found a jar file on my system here:

```
/home/cardamom/.p2/pool/plugins/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.moonrise-ui_0.8.9.201404052318.jar
```

I was able to open it with vim. It takes you first to a directory of contents which looks like this:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
META-INF/ 
plugin.xml 
themes/ 
themes/css/ 
themes/css/moonrise-ui-standalone.css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui-standalone_OSX.css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui-standalone_WIN.css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui.css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui_OSX.css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui_WIN.css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui_[OSX-patch].css 
themes/css/moonrise-ui_[WIN-patch].css 
com/ 
com/github/ 
com/github/eclipseuitheme/ 
com/github/eclipseuitheme/themes/ 
com/github/eclipseuitheme/themes/Activator.class 
com/github/eclipseuithemes/ 
com/github/eclipseuithemes/plugin/ 
com/github/eclipseuithemes/plugin/Activator.class
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~
```

`moonrise-ui-standalone.css` and `moonrise-ui.css` each have 2 occurences of `font-size`and I have tried changing both but it hasn't worked yet.

Does anyone know which would be the relevant file(s) where that css should be pasted in this case or if there is perhaps an easier way to achieve this in Eclipse Photon with PyDev and Moonrise theme?

Comment: My guess is that the Moonrise theme has set that in its plugin (so, you could try asking its maintainers if that's actually the case and how to customize their css files).

Comment: p.s.: my guess is that it's one of the `com.genuitec.eclipse.ui.common.platform` related files.

Comment: Thanks @FabioZadrozny I had a look at the 5 of those genuitec files, tail does not look muck like default_gtk or default_win. I won't waste time pasting code randomly, if nobody else has any ideas, may start an issue in GitHub Moonrise.